# Issue with Add more button html php

Tags: php, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('#add').click(function() {
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="text" name="actions[]" placeholder="Action items" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="form1" />
<div class="form-group">

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="actions[]" placeholder="Action Items" class="form-control name_list" /></td>

        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="submitabouc" id="i_submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </div>
  </form>
```

Output:

```
 [actions] => Array
        (
            [0] => tytytyt
        )
```

Output always get first value only.
Here Add more is working..but if i post value **i Got only first value**..I din't get Addmore field value please help me.Any help would be Appreciated

Comment: how are you getting the array? use CLASS instead of ID. ID should be unique

Comment: Are you submitting the form using ajax?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay nop just noraml form submit

Comment: Ok so you are printing the variable in php ? from $_POST ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay yep

Comment: @AlivetoDie i have updated the code please check

Comment: @juvajacob You are not getting it because, those new fields are added dynamically. which will not bind to DOM on submit. in order to get value of those fields, you need to submit via ajax, you can get value of those appended inputs values in javascript and you may post it from there.

Comment: Could you just show how you are pushing the text field values into the array?

Comment: @Rupal  no you are wrong. Check my comment screen-shot

Comment: @juvajacob  I have tested your code and it's working fine for me. although after submit the jquery added row's are gone but i got all the added data.check here:- https://prnt.sc/hzb3vi  And https://prnt.sc/hzb3z8  . So i am unable to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Rupal, that could be the issue if OP would be posting the form data using JS (ajax). But here it is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and it's working fine for me.

***Important:-*** *I have added complete code on single page.(and i have this much code only on the page, nothing else.)*

***form.php:-***

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="form1" />
    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="actions[]" placeholder="Action Items" class="form-control name_list" /></td>

            <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" name="submitabouc" id="i_submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </div>
</form>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
      var i = 1;
      $('#add').click(function() {
        i++;
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="text" name="actions[]" placeholder="Action items" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
      });
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
      });

    });
</script>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submitabouc'])){
   echo "<pre/>";print_r($_POST);
}

?>
```

Output:- https://prnt.sc/hzb3vi  And https://prnt.sc/hzb3z8